# Having some issue while setting virtualhost in apache2

Tags: apache2

I have some issue while setting virtualhost in apache2. I have three subdomains   (a.test.com, b.test.com, c.test.com) that are connected to same server. I setup virtualhost like below to make each subdomain show other site.

```
# Content of /etc/apache2/sites-available/a.test.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName a.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/a
</VirtualHost>

# Content of /etc/apache2/sites-available/b.test.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName b.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/b
</VirtualHost>
```

The reason that c.test.com.conf not exist is that I want to show 404 notfound or connection refused(cause c.test.com is not resolved) when client try to access c.test.com. But, when client try to access to c.test.com it shows a.test.com's result.

I already disabled 000-default but these settings are not working what I expected. What should I do to make c.test.com shows 404 notfound or connection refused?

This is result of `ls /etc/apache2/sites-available`

```
000-default.conf
a.test.com.conf
b.test.com.conf
```

This is result of `ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

```
a.test.com.conf
b.test.com.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

If no matching virtual host is found, then the first listed virtual host will be used.

Use the virtual host in `000-default.conf` to configure the behavior for domains that don't match one of your other virtual hosts. For example use a non-existing document root.

Comment: Thanks! I will use 000-default.conf for other domains.
Cheers.